# html/ js submit select with multible options by enter key

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a drop-down select list in which multiple items can be selected and is submitted by pressing enter, so without a button to submit it.

```
<select id="menu" multiple>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

```
function myFunction(event) {
    // Do stuff
 }

document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("keydown", myFunction)
```

I'm able to submit it and check for the enter key however, the problem is that when pressing enter a new option is selected and other selections that were made are deselected before it is submitted.

Any solution (or direction for) solving this?

Comment: So you do not have a form? You want keyup, not down

Comment: you need to add event.preventDefault() in your function callback - that should stop further processing of the event

Comment: In my case, it seems like the new selection is handled before the function is ever called, using keyup made this quite obvious.
For eq: I open the list, select multiple items, hold down enter, a new item is selected, release enter, function fires.
Or this is just a lack of knowledge on my end.